# solr - Deleting a row from the index, using the configuration files only

Tags: solr, solr4

I am updating my solr index using deltaQuery and deltaImportQuery attributes in data-config.xml.
In my condition I write

```
where MyDoc.LastModificationTime > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'
```

then after I add a row I trigger an update using data-config.xml.

Now, sometimes I delete a row.
How can I implement this with configuration files only
(without sending a delete rest command to solr ).

Lets say my object is not deleted but its status is changed to deleted.
I dont index that status field, as I want to hold only the live rows. (otherwise I could have just filtered it)
Is there a way to do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't mention anywhere I assume you didn't try this so far,

You can use deletedPkQuery supported by DataImportHandler. You can just configure the query which returns Ids (Solr document ID) which needs to be deleted during delta-import.

You can do something similar mentioned in:

http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/03/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-removing-data-from-index/